# How do I open an internally created pdf in Xamarin.Android via a FileProvider in the default system pdf app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I created a `.pdf` file in the private local directory I got via (I try to work with the minimum of permissions):

```
string targetBaseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal,
    Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create
    );
```

The [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file#java) suggests that file should be shared via a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing).

I also tried to get some code to start an intent, and I'm currently at:

```
var fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath);

var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask); 
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetType("application/pdf");
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

This starts the share dialog for a pdf file but while the Adobe Pdf reader gets opened it shows an empty view and not my pdf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your URI with FileProvider. Since android uri will give you `file://` while FileProvider will give you `content://`, which you actually need:

```
public static Android.Net.Uri WrapFileWithUri(Context context,Java.IO.File file)
{
    Android.Net.Uri result;
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < (BuildVersionCodes)24)
    {
        result = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
    }
    else
    {
        result = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
    }
    return result;
}
```

File can be createed this way:

```
var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
```

Then you can open it:

```
    public static void View(Context context, string path, string mimeType) 
    {
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        Java.IO.File document = new Java.IO.File(path);            
        viewIntent.SetDataAndType(UriResolver.WrapFileWithUri(context,document),mimeType);            
        viewIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        viewIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(viewIntent, "your text"));
    }
```

Be aware, that this line

```
viewIntent.SetDataAndType(UriResolver.WrapFileWithUri(context,document),mimeType);
```

does not equal to SetData and SetType separate commands.

And yes, you need to add FileProvider to your manifest:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Also you need to create Resources\xml folder with provider_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>  
  <files-path name="internal_files" path="." />

</paths>
```

Comment: Did you put the `WrapFileWithUri`-function into a UriResolver class?

Comment: @Christian yes, sorry for missing this.

Comment: Is there anything else that the UriResolver class does that is important here? Or can "UriResolver." basically be removed from that code?

Comment: I'm also not clear where I get a context within Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @Christian You can remove UriResolver class definition. Context is an Activity or There is also Application.Context, not quite sure if it will work or not. According to common sence both should work.

Comment: When I create that xml file I get during the startup of my app the error`Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ra_micro.RA_Krypt/md5ac266b5641403f314bbc23831457c9e5.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setId(int)' on a null object reference` whether or not the part about the manifest gets added.

Comment: delete bin and obj folders on Android project and rebuild it

Comment: I needed to add an additional path for images, but now that works. Thank you very much.

Comment: This code works well on Google Pixel but when I use it on a Huawei device to share a PDF, roughly every second time the PDF can't be opened.